# When deleting an image from inside app directory, appears automatically in gallery

Tags: android, image, gallery

I don't know if its a normal behaviour or not, but I have noticed that when I delete an image (created previously from within my app) from my app, it appears automatically in the android image gallery.

What I want is that the image always stay inside the app directory, and if I want to delete it, remove it from everywhere. (for security reasons).

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well,

The problem was the "getImageUri" function:

```
 public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, globalVariable.getIntCompressioImatge(), bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "TitleImage", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

inside the function when getting the path, was inserting the image in the image gallery. 
Changing it solve the problem.

Hope this will help someone like me :)